# Cannot hide the events in default Calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar

I created overlays to colour code the calendar. All events show twice because I cannot hide them in the default view. Even though I make the appropriate selection in the 'Filter' section and click 'Ok', the calendar does not remember my selection and reverts to 'Show all items in this view'.

Answer (score 1):

Provide your steps with screenshots.

Verify the following things:

1. Ensure you are modifying the default view.
2. All events have values in this column.
3. Ensure you have checked the "Show items only when the following is true" radio button, then enter the filter.

   [image]
4. Use IE with 32-bit.

Besides, test in another Calendar. See if you can create a view with filter.

Refer to the steps in the following blogs to learn more about how to color Calendar using Overlay, check your steps:

https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-color-code-sharepoint-calendars/

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/color-code-events-on-a-sharepoint-calendar/